# Find all tables with specified column name and set values to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I know how to find all tables with specified column name in database:

```
SELECT  TABLE_NAME
        , COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE   COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Name%'
```

As a result I get a table with `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_NAME`. Is it possible to set all values in columns received by query to NULL?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL to accomplish this.

Comment: Use a cursor and dynamic SQL should get you there.

Comment: But why do you want to do something like that? Maybe you should re-design your database instead. If really needed, take your time and do it properly, one update for each table. (Think if somebody else by accident adds a new column with that specific name, and data suddenly gets lost...!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Dynamic Sql`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)=''

SELECT @sql += 'update ' + TABLE_NAME + ' set ' + COLUMN_NAME + '= NULL '
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%Name%'

--print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: For efficiency mayby add where COLUMN_NAME is not nulll

Comment: @Blam - Is there any possibility for `NULL` value in `COLUMN_NAME` column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table

Comment: To the @sql update statement so it does not take the overhead of a lock on a value that is already null

Answer (score 0):

`sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented by widely used. It loops through each table and perform the specified statement. `[?]` is the stand-in for the table name. Please back up your database before trying this.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE [?] SET SomeColumn = NULL'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define each table and each column in your query. For that you need to select tables and columns dynamically and execute it. You can use a cursor to this dynamically

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)=''
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @PreviousTableName VARCHAR(100)='' 
DECLARE @PreviousColumnName NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @ROWNO INT
DECLARE @MAXCOUNT INT

DECLARE @UPDATESQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COLSSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)


-- Here you declare which all columns you need to loop in Cursor
DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
-- Find Row number for each table
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME) RNO,
-- Gets the count of columns in each table
COUNT(COLUMN_NAME) OVER(PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME) CNT     
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%TE%'
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 

OPEN CUR


FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
INTO @TableName,@ColumnName,@ROWNO,@MAXCOUNT

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SET @PreviousColumnName = @PreviousColumnName + @ColumnName + '=NULL,'

    -- If current row is last record of the table in the loop
    IF(@ROWNO = @MAXCOUNT)
    BEGIN
        SET @UPDATESQL = 'UPDATE '+@TableName+' SET ' + @PreviousColumnName
        SET @UPDATESQL = LEFT(@UPDATESQL, LEN(@UPDATESQL) - 1)
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @UPDATESQL
        SET @PreviousColumnName = ''            
    END

    -- Fetches next record and increments the loop
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR 
    INTO @TableName,@ColumnName,@ROWNO,@MAXCOUNT
END 

CLOSE CUR;
DEALLOCATE CUR;
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1b76/2)**